# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker

Accidentally,  my docker goes wrong, and cannot be started.

`docker ps`gives the following error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

And `systemctl status docker.service` gives the following outputs:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
       └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2018-11-20 18:27:11 PST; 11s ago
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 16519 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --host=fd:// --add-runtime=nvidia=/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16519 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 20 18:27:09 loccalhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 20 18:27:09 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 18:27:09 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 18:27:11 loccalhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Comment: After I removed `-H fd://` in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`, it is working, as shown in [link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33931#issuecomment-439934007)

Answer (score 1):

A [more recent answer](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33931#issuecomment-453840775) in the same thread mentioned by skyuua suggests the following (it changes the -H fd:// to -H unix://)

> sudo systemctl edit docker.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

followed by

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>
> sudo systemctl restart docker.service

On my Ubuntu 16.04 with docker 18.0.3 this rewrites the file */etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf*  which allowed docker to start correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We ran sudo apt-get update, our docker version got updated too, it changed from  18.09.1 to 18.09.3, and docker went haywire. After digging online, I fould following solution that solved issue for us.

```
sudo systemctl edit docker.service 

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-ce -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

then restart service

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```